# How can I determine if value from array lies between values at all parallel indices of two additional arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have four arrays, with the following roles:

1. All existing start dates (unchecked)
2. All existing end dates (unchecked)
3. Selected item start dates (checked)
4. Selected item end dates (checked)

1 and 2 are contain the pool of start and end timestamps for all unselected events in a set.

3 and 4 are populated with start and end timestamps when checkboxes associated with events are checked, and when they are unchecked the the timestamp is removed.

The outcome should be that if the date ranges of unselected items conflicts with that of newly selected items, prevent them from being selected and visually show they are disabled options.

I currently have it comparing values of all unchecked items with the *most recently checked* date in the comparison array, but it ignores the ones prior. This means that I may select one, conflicting dates are disabled, but when I select another available option, the ones previously disabled are re-enabled.

I'm not 100% sure how to make sure that all unchecked items are compared with all checked items and disabled based on whether the dates conflict or not. Would adding a nested for loop within the existing one be the best way to approach this?

*P.S. I'm aware there are some strange selectors and extra work to format dates, but the people I am doing this for insist that the date format be MON ## - ## (same month) and MON ## - MON ## (different months) and the date be contained in a small tag in the checkbox label.*

```
    var camp_dates;
    var camp_start;
    var camp_end;
    var other_camp_dates;
    var other_camp_start;
    var other_camp_end;
    var checked_start = [];
    var checked_end = [];
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();

    // Change checkbox apply filters
    $("#gform_11 input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
        //Reset list of checked items
        checked_start = [];
        checked_end = [];

        camp_dates = $("label[for='" + $(this).attr("id") + "'] small").html().split("-");

        camp_start = camp_dates[0].split(" ");

        camp_end = camp_dates[1].split(" ");

        //If no month in end date, assume same month as first (Ex. Jul 06-22 == Jul 06 - Jul 22)
        if (camp_end.length == 1){
            camp_end.unshift(camp_start[0]);
        }

        //rejoin day and months, add year to parse for timestamp
        camp_start = Date.parse(camp_start.join(" ") + ", " + year);
        camp_end = Date.parse(camp_end.join(" ") + ", " + year);

        //Take empty start and arrays and add dates for selections
        $(".gfield_checkbox input:checked").each(function(){
            //All currently checked items
            checked_start.push(camp_start);
            checked_end.push(camp_end);
        });

        $(".gfield_checkbox input:not(:checked) + label small").each(function(){

            //Gen values for all unselected items
            other_camp_dates = $(this).html().split("-");
            other_camp_start = other_camp_dates[0].split(" ");
            other_camp_end = other_camp_dates[1].split(" ");

            //If no month in end date, assume same month as first
            if (other_camp_end.length == 1){
                other_camp_end.unshift(other_camp_start[0]);
            }

            //rejoin day and months, add year to parse for timestamp
            other_camp_start = Date.parse(other_camp_start.join(" ") + ", " + year);
            other_camp_end = Date.parse(other_camp_end.join(" ") + ", " + year);

            // Loop through arrays of start/end dates and compare to each unselected item - apply fade, disable, color
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < checked_start.length; i++) {
                if ( other_camp_start >= checked_start[i] && other_camp_start < checked_end[i] ||
                    other_camp_end > checked_start[i] && other_camp_end <= checked_end[i] ){
                    // If there is conflict
                    $(this).css("color", "red").parent().fadeTo("slow",0.5).siblings("input").not(":checked").attr("disabled", true);
                } else {
                    $(this).css("color", "#7E7E7E").parent().fadeTo("slow",1).siblings("input").attr("disabled", false);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

http://codepen.io/wjramos/pen/BywyRY

Comment: It would help to see your HTML

Comment: Even better, do you think you could create a [JS fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net) we could work with? With sample dates and a structure that would help us understand the problem better?

Comment: Included a pen in original post, stripped it down to the minimum

Comment: BTW - you should really cater for start-end ranges that span a New Year, eg Dec 29-Jan 1. May be unlikely ... but possible.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like it might be pretty messy. Would it make sense to simply add a year (31,536,000 seconds) to the end timestamp if the end date is less than the start date due to the year wrapping?

Comment: @Roamer-1888, Added to your answer to test it out:

Adding 1 unix year to end date if the end date ends up being less than the start date


`start_date = Date.parse(start.join(" ") + ", " + year),

end_date = Date.parse(end.join(" ") + ", " + year);

return {

start: start_date,

end: (end_date < start_date ? end_date + 31556926 : end_date) // Add a year if it end date is in the following year

};`

If I wanted this all to execute once on page load (for instances where the page loads and items are already checked such as navigating back), any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Adding 31556926 is unreliable because of Leap Years. It's better to use re-parse the end date with `year +1`. See Edit 1 in my answer.

Comment: And see Edit 2 for setting the state of everything on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is simpler than the code would imply.

First, repeteated code for parsing out dates can be eliminated by writing a `parseDates()` function, which :

- returns an object with `.start` and `.end` properties.
- can be used as a `.map()` callback, once for checked and once for unchecked checkboxes.

Then, what remains to be done is to check all unchecked dates against all checked dates in nested loops, and manage the unchecked items' disabled status. A major factor in doing this is to re-enable items only when all the disabled items are known - ie after the two nested loops have completed.

The code should be something like this :

```
// Change checkbox apply filters
$("#gform_11 input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();

    //A utility function for parsing out start and end dates
    function parseDates() {
        var dates = $(this).html().split("-"),
            start = dates[0].split(" "),
            end = dates[1].split(" ");
        //If no month in end date, assume same month as first (Ex. Jul 06-22 == Jul 06 - Jul 22)
        if (end.length == 1) {
            end.unshift(start[0]);
        }
        //return an object with .start and .end properties
        return {
            start: Date.parse(start.join(" ") + ", " + year), //rejoin 
            end: Date.parse(end.join(" ") + ", " + year) //rejoin 
        };
    }

    //A utility function for comparing a checked date with an unchecked date
    function compareDateRanges(checked, unchecked) {
        return ( unchecked.start >= checked.start && unchecked.start < checked.end ) ||
            ( unchecked.end > checked.start && unchecked.end <= checked.end )
    }

    var $checked = $(".gfield_checkbox input:checked");
    var $unchecked = $(".gfield_checkbox input:not(:checked)").removeClass('disabled');

    var checkedDates = $checked.siblings("label").find("small").map(parseDates).get();//make array of start-end objects for checked inputs
    var uncheckedDates = $unchecked.siblings("label").find("small").map(parseDates).get();//make array of start-end objects for unchecked inputs

    for(var i=0; i<checkedDates.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<uncheckedDates.length; j++) {
            if(compareDateRanges(checkedDates[i], uncheckedDates[j])) {
                // If there is conflict
                $unchecked.eq(j).addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', true).siblings("label").find("small").css('color', 'red').parent().fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
            }
        }
    }
    //when all disabled elements are known, all others can be eneabled.
    $unchecked.not(".disabled").attr('disabled', false).siblings("label").find("small").css('color', '#7E7E7E').parent().fadeTo('slow', 1);
});
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JorXXJ?editors=101)**

### Edit 1

To cater for date ranges that might span a new year :

```
//A utility function for parsing out start and end dates
function parseDates() {
    var dates = $(this).siblings("label").find("small").html().split("-"),
        start = dates[0].split(" "),
        end = dates[1].split(" ");
    //If no month in end date, assume same month as first (Ex. Jul 06-22 == Jul 06 - Jul 22)
    if (end.length == 1) {
        end.unshift(start[0]);
    }
    var obj = {
        start: Date.parse(start.join(" ") + ", " + year), //rejoin 
        end: Date.parse(end.join(" ") + ", " + year) //rejoin 
    }
    // Test for the date range spanning a New Year.
    // If necessary, reparse `end` with next year's date
    if(obj.end < obj.start) {
        obj.end = Date.parse(end.join(" ") + ", " + (year + 1));
    }
    //return an object with .start and .end properties
    return obj;
}
```

### Edit 2

To execute on page load, trigger the click handler for the first checkbox :

```
$("#gform_11 input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    ... ...
}).eq(0).triggerHandler('click');
```

*It doesn't matter if the first checkbox is checked or not as everything is calculated all through regardless of the element's :checked state.*

Comment: Thank you, it took me a little while to digest it, but this is a clever solution that I can learn a lot from. Concise and implements features of JS I have never used before

Comment: Very clever approach.

Comment: Once you've got your mind round `.map(parseDates).get()`, the rest is extremely simple .... and designed to keep the original code's fades.

Comment: Triggering the click event works perfectly! I haven't been able to determine whether the date spanning a new year works yet. There does also appear to be a typo in the parseDates function in that `.siblings("label").find("small")` won't work because the function is called in your original code like `.siblings("label").find("small").map(parseDates).get();`. Would it make more sense to have the traversal inside or outside of the function?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say, I moved `.siblings("label").find("small")` inside the function as its the same in both calls, which become - `var checkedDates = $checked.map(parseDates).get();` and `var uncheckedDates = $unchecked.map(parseDates).get();`.

Comment: It's probably more logical to have the traversal outside, but more compact inside. You *pays your money and takes your pick* as we say around here.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be having trouble with the way you enable / disable your checkboxes. You are looping through each unselected items, and if they conflict with a selected one, you disable them, if they don't, you enable them.

Here is why it is a problem: let's say that you have an unchecked date that conflicts with a checked one. You disable the unchecked one.

But later in the loop, when you check it with another one and there is no conflict, you reenable it. It should stay disabled if it was disabled somewhere along the loop.

Another problem: where you have your comment "`//Take empty start and arrays and add dates for selections`", you push the same values over and over (`camp_start` & `camp_end`) without getting every selected dates.

Here is a revised version:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var camp_dates,
        other_camp_dates,
        checked_dates = [],
        year = new Date().getFullYear();

    // Change checkbox apply filters
    $("#gform_11 input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
        //Reset list of checked items
        checked_dates = [];

        camp_dates = formatDates( $("label[for='" + $(this).attr("id") + "'] small").html() );

        //Take empty checked_dates and add dates for selections
        $(".gfield_checkbox input:checked + label small").each(function(){
            //All currently checked items
            checked_dates.push( formatDates( $(this).html() ) );
        });

        // For each unchecked item
        $(".gfield_checkbox input:not(:checked) + label small").each(function(){
            //Get the dates
            other_camp_dates = formatDates( $(this).html() );

            // Enable the checkbox before matching it with all checked_dates
            // If we don't do that now, imagine we have a date that conflicts (we disable it),
            // and the next one does not conflict : we reenable it. Not what we want.
            $(this).css("color", "#7E7E7E").parent().css("opacity",1).siblings("input").attr("disabled", false);

            // Loop through arrays of checked_dates and compare to the current unchecked item
            var i, l = checked_dates.length;
            for (i = 0; i<l; i++) {
                if ( other_camp_dates.start >= checked_dates[i].start && other_camp_dates.start < checked_dates[i].end ||
                    other_camp_dates.end > checked_dates[i].start && other_camp_dates.end <= checked_dates[i].end ){

                    //Conflict
                    $(this).css("color", "red").parent().css("opacity",.5).siblings("input").not(":checked").attr("disabled", true);
                }
                // If there is no conflict for this one, there may be one for a previous one,
                // so we don't enable it here
            }
        });
    });

    // It's messy enough to make it a function and not rewrite it
    function formatDates(str){
        var dates = str.split("-"),
            start_date = dates[0].split(" "),
            end_date = dates[1].split(" ");
        if (end_date.length == 1){
            end_date.unshift(start_date[0]);
        }
        start_date = Date.parse(start_date.join(" ") + ", " + year);
        end_date = Date.parse(end_date.join(" ") + ", " + year);
        return {
            "start" : start_date,
            "end"   : end_date
        };
    }
}); // jQuery(document).ready
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: Thank you, this was a very clear explanation of why my approach was not giving the intended result, and your revised example is concise while not being radically different.